# What expression types are allowed in a derive macro's name-value helper attributes?

Tags: rust, macros

Rust's derive macros allow [helper attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macro-helper-attributes), e.g.

```rust
#[derive(HelperAttr)]
struct Struct {
    #[helper] field: ()
}
```

According to the [`syn` documentation](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.Attribute.html), an attribute can take the name-value form where the value is a Rust expression:

> Meta::NameValue — attributes with an = sign after the path, followed by a Rust expression. For example #[path = "sys/windows.rs"].

So I tried:

```rust
#[values = ["a", "b"]]
```

Which does not work. Strings work. Numbers work. Bool works. Arrays, it seems no. The compiler errors.

```
error: unexpected expression: `["a", "b"]`
 --> tests/test1.rs:5:16
  |
5 |     #[values = ["a", "b"]]
  |
```

But the `syn` doc's type definitions seem to indicate it any Rust expression should be supported.

Where is it documented what is supported? What is actually supported as a value in a name-value attribute?

Comment: Weird. For completeness, what is the error you get with the array syntax? Is it from your derive macro or before it?

Comment: @kmdreko Quite unhelpful, really. `error: unexpected expression: ["a", "b"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Although the rust language [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html?highlight=attribute#attributes) states `Expression` as a valid token following the `=` after `SimplePath` in attributes, most expressions (tuples, closures ]belong to the family as well) aren't valid here. I suppose this should have been `LiteralExpression`.

In the rust compiler source [code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a327e753bc873d5f5dc1820151a6cdf3dac0a39c/compiler/rustc_ast/src/ast.rs) (rust/compiler/rustc_ast/src
/ast.rs), this syntax is listed as a `MetaItem` with `kind = NamedValue(MetaItemLit)`, `MetaItemLit` again has `kind: LitKind`, and `LitKind` only has enum values for literal expressions.

In libraries a common pattern are `MetaList` terms in place of array like arguments.
e.g.

```rust
#[derive(HelperAttr)]
struct MyStruct {
    #[values(1, 2, 3)] // also #[values([1, 2, 3])] works here
    my_field: u32,
}
```

which can be read with `syn` via the following definition

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(HelperAttr, attributes(values))]
pub fn derive_example(item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {

    let tokens = item.clone();
    let ast = parse_macro_input!(tokens as DeriveInput);

    let struct_: syn::DataStruct = match ast.data {
        syn::Data::Struct(data) => data,
        _ => panic!("Failed to parse HelperAttr, didn't parse struct"),
    };
   
    for field in struct_.fields.iter() {
        for attr in field.attrs.iter() {
            if attr.path().is_ident("values") {
                let meta_list = attr.meta.require_list();
                if let Ok(meta_list) = meta_list {
                    println!("{:#?}", meta_list.tokens);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    TokenStream::new()
}
```

Comment: Do you have a resource that lists which expression types are or aren't valid? Even just compiler source or off-site discussion would be good.

Comment: updated my answer with references to the compiler, at the moment LitKind is on line 1815, MetaItemLit ~ 1752, MetaItemKind ~ 521.